# Delete a row if it has green background in 15 minutes after it has been marked green in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to write a google sheets script that would delete rows that have green background.

**More detailed explanation:**

I have a google sheets table in which:

- first row represents the names of the columns (3)
- all the following rows represent some 3-column data

**What I need to do:**

When any of the rows in the spreadsheet (except first one) is changed to have a green background, the `setTimeout` function should start, which would eventually delete all the data of the green row and set its background as white again.

**What I've done so far:**

I have a function that should return the hex value of the background color of the range:

```
function getHexValue(range) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range).getBackground();
}
```

I have a function that returns `true` if the input hex value is green:

```
function isGreen(color) {
  return  ["#b6d7a8", "#d9ead3", "#93c47d", "#6aa84f", "#38761d", "#274e13"].some(function(el) { return color === el; });
}
```

I've also tried to loop through the range and check for the background color in the following way:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getRange('A2:C');
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();


  for (var i = 1; i < numRows; ++i) {

    Logger.log(getHexValue(ss.getRange(i, 1)));
  }
```

However, I keep getting the *'Invalid coordinates or range size'* exceptions and, hence, cannot move forward. Besides, google prompts me that using `getRange` function in a loop is not a very good idea and can significantly slow down the script execution.

---

How do I approach my task in a correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can find green.  Generally, I like to get all of the data at one time.  That's why I use getDataRange() a lot. Once the data is in an array you can whip through it pretty quickly.  The only trick is output.  Remember, the data is in a 2D array.  So if you're not using all of the array to setValues you may have to use the array itself to help you setup the right size range for the setValues() command.

```
function findGreenRow() 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var rg=sh.getDataRange();
    var cA=rg.getBackgrounds();
    var gA=[];
    var green='#00ff00'
    for(var i=1;i<cA.length;i++)
    {
      if(cA[i][0] == green && cA[i][1] == green && cA[i][2]==green)
      {
        gA.push(sh.getRange(i+1,1,1,3).getA1Notation());
      }
    }
  Logger.log(gA);
  return gA
}
```

Here's a possible beginning to a more complete solution. It has a menu for the spreedsheet so you can run it from the spreadsheet and it displays the row ranges in a text area and it shows you how to use the withSuccessHandler for callbacks.

FindGreenRows.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function findGreen()
      {
        google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(dispGreenRanges)
            .findGreenRows();
      }
      function dispGreenRanges(gA)
      {
        $('#txt1').val(gA.join(','));
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1">
      <textarea id="txt1" rows="4" cols="35"></textarea>
      <br /><input id="btn0" type="button" value="Find Green" title="Find green rows." onClick="findGreen();" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs

```
function findGreenRows() 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var rg=sh.getDataRange();
    var cA=rg.getBackgrounds();
    var gA=[];
    var green='#00ff00';
    for(var i=1;i<cA.length;i++)
    {
      if(cA[i][0] == green && cA[i][1] == green && cA[i][2]==green)
      {
        gA.push(sh.getRange(i+1,1,1,3).getA1Notation());
      }
    }
  Logger.log(gA);
  return gA
}

function showGreenDialog()
{
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('FindGreenRows');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Find Green');
}

function makeGreenMenu()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('The Green Menu')
    .addItem('Find Green', 'showGreenDialog')
    .addToUi();
}
```